# Debugging AWS Lambda (Python) Locally in VS Code with out using SAM-CLI

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, container-image

I'm trying to debug AWS lambda (python) function created using container image locally on VSCode. I don't want to use SAM CLI as my Directory structure don't contain template.yml. Is there a way to debug the code in VSCode while running the container from the image for AWS Lambda?

Comment: Have you tried aws-sam-vscode ( https://github.com/eduardolucioac/aws-sam-vscode ) ❓❤️

Answer (score 0):

I refer to this [page](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/05/debugging-an-aws-lambda-function-locally-with-visual-studio-code-vs-code-on-windows-linux-and-mac/) which can help.

Add the following code to your `launch.json`:

Windows:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${env:USERPROFILE}/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-lambda-test-tool-6.0.exe",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
    ]
}
```

Linux and Mac：

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${env:HOME}/.dotnet/tools/dotnet-lambda-test-tool-6.0",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        }
    ]
}
```